# Set excel/ googlesheet workbook to automatically update rows in all worksheets when you add in one?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have multiple worksheets in a workbook where I have multiple client details, I am trying to see if I can basically set my workbook to be able to auto update when I add a row in one sheet and that automatically creates that row in other sheets too!
Example:
I create Sheet1!A5 with name mark, can we set it to basically add row with mark in Sheet2!A5?

Thank you!
Hope it’s something doable! Basically been adding manually in 7 different google sheets when I have to add a new client!

I have tried watching into multiple websites but don’t have anything concrete!

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
={Sheet2!A5:A}
```

so as soon as you create a new row it should be reflected